# "strace -p pid" gives "attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted"

Tags: android, strace

I have written an android application which monitors system calls of running processes, but all what I get is "Operation not permitted". I have tried to disable SElinux and enable root access on strace using "chmod 4777 strace" and chown "root:root strace" but I still cannot solve the issue. The application is running on an emulator 4.3 (API 18).

Answer (score 1):

Processes can disable tracing and there is no way one can attach, even as root.

EPERM can be triggered if the target process either cannot receive signals from strace (if running as root is successful this is excluded, although I'm not sure strace actually handles stuff well), the target process is itself setuid (they disable tracing), as well as if tracing has simply been disabled by the process itself. Also, a process can be traced by at most one debugger.

Processes which are not dumpable cannot be attached to by strace. A process can set itself as not dumpable, and also it happens automatically on UID changes (either due to setuid bit or setuid system call)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I noticed when running for instance "Strace cat  "file" -o /path" from the android application the output of tracing  "cat"  on "file" generates a file according the specified path. However, with " Strace -p(PID zygote process) -f -o /path I get an empty file knowing that I tried to fork random applications in hopes to acquire syscalls from the new generated children processes associated with these applications ( Zygote is the parent of all android application processes).

Comment: I tried also to direclty strace a child process without tracing zygote but in vains, I experienced the same issue. What do you suggest ? I read somewhere in a forum whose I cannot recall the name, that it would be possible to modify the kernel in order to make the tracing happens. Currenlty I am working on API 15.

Comment: For modifying the kernel you need a rooted device (I guess you have it). The API is what is above the kernel so it's actually irelevant. Replacing the kernel is not something an app can do.

Comment: The kernel can be modified to not perform the security checks. Still, you'd fail tracing already traced processes.

Comment: The problem is the apps themselves can tell the kernel they don't want to be traced and no security policy can override this.

Comment: Actually, I think this is possible. I have solved the issue by using a hacking trick ;)

Comment: Interesting. Did it involve disabling certain kernel security checks?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases executing strace on Android fails with "ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted" since strace is already running in Android

$ adb shell su -c ps | grep strace
root      15861 1     1056   4        do_wait 00000452cc S

Once the old running strace process is killed, new invocations might succeed:

$ adb shell su -c pkill strace